# Undefined reference to AndroidStudio JNI

Tags: c++, android-studio, jni

При попытке компиляции возникает классическая ошибка Undefined reference to

```
Error:(72) undefined reference to 'Cell::num()'
Error:(111) undefined reference to 'Cell::Cell(int, int, int)'
Error:(175) undefined reference to 'Cell::num()'
Error:(49) undefined reference to 'Cell::Cell()'
Error:(127) undefined reference to 'Cell::num()'
Error:(158) undefined reference to 'Cell::num()'
```

Сверялся с учебником, гуглом и так далее, делаю все правильно, Cell.cpp

```
#include <android/log.h>
#include "Cell.h"

Cell::Cell() {
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    number = 0;
}

Cell::Cell(int x, int y, int number) {
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    this->number = number;
}

void Cell::print() {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "out", "(x = %d, y = %d, num = %d)\n", x, y, number);
}

int Cell::num() {
    return number;
}
```

Cell.h

```
#ifndef SUDOKU_CELL_H
#define SUDOKU_CELL_H


class Cell {

public:

    Cell();

    Cell(int, int, int);

    int num();

    void print();

private:
    int number;
    int x, y;
};


#endif //SUDOKU_CELL_H
```

Ошибки возникают в коде при попытке обращения к объекту класса Cell через индексы массива

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>

#include <android/log.h>
#include "Cell.h"

/**
* Generator
*/
void generate();

/**
* Print Helpers
*/
void printBoard();


extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jstring


JNICALL
Java_iam_thevoid_sudoku_MainActivity_generate(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject /* this */) {
    generate();
    printBoard();
}

Cell board[WIDTH][HEIGHT];

void generate()
{
     ... // Example
     Cell c(nextX, nextY, number);

     board[nextY][nextX] = c;
     int num = board[nextY][nextX].num();
}

//
// -------------------------- PRINTER -------------------------------------
//

void printBoard() {
    ...

    ...
}
```

Я впервые пытаюсь запустить проект с JNI, возможно я делаю не так что то супер очевидное, но советы вроде https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096819/jni-and-gradle-in-android-studio/21111458#21111458 меня не выручили. Что я могу делать не так?

Comment: Ощущение, что в вашем проекте при построении забыт файл `cell.c`. Он точно входит в проект? Компилируется, линкуется?

Comment: Точно, его нужно было добавить в CMakeLists.txt